# Find the first record according to a chain of JOIN rules in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find a "best fit" record by using a multi-field relation.
I need to JOIN based on 3 fields, if this fails use 2 fileds, and if this fails use 1-filed condition, etc.
Such chain can be long, fields can vary, etc.
How to achieve this.

Below I present some ideas but somehow feel this could be done better.

**First way** (I don't like the UNION because I guess the engine will execute them all regardless of the LIMIT 1 clause which could work as "stop on first found":

```
SELECT A1, A2, A3, B4 FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT B4 FROM
      ((SELECT B4, 1 AS ORD FROM B 
            WHERE B.B1 = A.A1 AND B.B2 = A.B2 AND B.B3 = A.A3)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT B4, 2 AS ORD FROM B 
            WHERE B.B1 = A.A1 AND B.B2 = A.B2)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT B4, 3 AS ORD FROM B 
            WHERE B.B1 = A.A1)) ORDER BY ORD ASC LIMIT 1);
```

**Second way** (here I don't like the repeated SELECT IN WHEN and again in THEN section, also it is only good when a single field is returned

```
SELECT A1, A2, A3,
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS 
            (SELECT B4 FROM B WHERE B.B1 = A.A1 AND B.B2 = A.B2 AND B.B3 = A.A3) 
            THEN 
            (SELECT B4 FROM B WHERE B.B1 = A.A1 AND B.B2 = A.B2 AND B.B3 = A.A3 LIMIT 1)
        WHEN EXISTS 
            (SELECT B4 FROM B WHERE B.B1 = A.A1 AND B.B2 = A.B2) 
            THEN 
            (SELECT B4 FROM B WHERE B.B1 = A.A1 AND B.B2 = A.B2 LIMIT 1)
        WHEN EXISTS 
            (SELECT B4 FROM B WHERE B.B1 = A.A1) 
            THEN (SELECT B4 FROM B WHERE B.B1 = A.A1 LIMIT 1)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS B4
FROM A;
```

I use postgreSQL 9.6 but the questions should be treated as standard SQL question.

Code to test:

```
CREATE TABLE A (A1 INT, A2 INT, A3 INT);
CREATE TABLE B (B1 INT, B2 INT, B3 INT, B4 VARCHAR(2));

INSERT INTO A VALUES 
    (10, 20, 30),
    (11, 21, 31),
    (12, 22, 32),
    (13, 23, 33),
    (14, 24, 34);

INSERT INTO B VALUES 
    (10, 20,    30, 'A1'),
    (11, 21,    0,  'B'),
    (12, 0,     0,  'C'),
    (10, 23,    30, 'A2'),
    (14, 0,     34, 'D');

/*
EXPECTED RESULT
10, 20, 30, A1
11, 21, 31, B
12, 22, 32, C
*/
```

Comment: please provide some samples and expected result

Comment: @maSTAShuFu: done

Comment: what's the logic of the result?

Comment: i don't know how made this work but your field B4 can only have 1 character

Comment: First record: The relation using A1, A2, A3, Second record: using A1 and A2 , Third only using A1. 4th record in B is not selected (I want a single record not all), 5th is not selected - there is no rule to lookup by A1 and A3 only

Answer (score 2):

You can use `left join`.  Here is one way:

```
select a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, coalesce(b1.B4, b2.b4, b3.b4) as b4
from A left join
     b b1
     on b1.b1 = a.a1 and b1.b2 = a.b2 and b1.b3 = a.b3 left join
     b b2
     on b1.b1 = a.a1 and b1.b2 = a.b2 and b1.a1 is null left join
     b b3
     on b1.b1 = a.a1 and b2.b1 is null and b1.b1 is null;
```

The above could return multiple rows.  If you only want one row, then you can try:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.b4
        from b
        where b.b1 = a.a1
        order by (b.b2 = a.a2 and b.b3 = a.a3)::int desc,
                 (b.b2 = a.a2)::int desc
        limit 1
       ) as b4
from a;
```

This is not as efficient.  And, the query can be phrased as a lateral join -- particularly useful if you want to return more than one value.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is a very elegant and clean solution. I need to compare its execution plan with the LATERAL version posted by Used_By_Already on some large data set, It will take me some time but will be back with the results

Comment: Just noticed, this is not limiting to a single record found in B. Instead results are multiplied by a number of records found in B. But the value returned in the COALESCE is correct.

Comment: `order by (b.b2 = a.a2 and b.b3 = a.a3)::int desc, (b.b2 = a.a2)::int desc` the a table has column starting with a (not b.b2 = a.`b`2 etc)  but interesting use of true/false +1

Answer (score 1):

`left join lateral` may work for you on this as it allows limiting the results to one row (each):.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (A1 INT, A2 INT, A3 INT);
> CREATE TABLE table2 (B1 INT, B2 INT, B3 INT, B4 VARCHAR(10));
>
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES 
>     (10, 20, 30),
>     (11, 21, 31),
>     (12, 22, 32),
>     (13, 23, 33),
>     (14, 24, 34);
>
> INSERT INTO table2 VALUES 
>     (10, 20,    30, 'A1'),
>     (11, 21,    0,  'B'),
>     (12, 0,     0,  'C'),
>     (10, 23,    30, 'A2'),
>     (14, 0,     34, 'D');
> ```

> ```
> select
> a1,a2,a3,coalesce(ljl1.b4,ljl2.b4,ljl3.b4)
> from table1
> left join lateral (
>   select b4 from table2
>   where table1.a1 = b1 and table1.a2 = b2 and table1.a3 = b3
>   order by b1, b2, b3, b4
>   limit 1
>   ) ljl1 ON true
> left join lateral (
>   select b4 from table2
>   where table1.a1 = b1 and table1.a2 = b2
>   order by b1, b2, b3, b4
>   limit 1
>   ) ljl2 On true
> left join lateral (
>   select b4 from table2
>   where table1.a1 = b1
>   order by b1, b2, b3, b4
>   limit 1
>   ) ljl3 ON true
> ```
>
> ```
> a1 | a2 | a3 | coalesce
> -: | -: | -: | :-------
> 10 | 20 | 30 | A1      
> 11 | 21 | 31 | B       
> 12 | 22 | 32 | C       
> 13 | 23 | 33 | null    
> 14 | 24 | 34 | D
> ```

*dbfiddle [demo here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=04ce505964b67151bd9ed57062466a4b)*

You can add `where coalesce(ljl1.b4,ljl2.b4,ljl3.b4) IS NOT NULL` if required to more closely match the expected result, but I'm not sure why his row isn;t in your expected result:

> ```
> 14 | 24 | 34 | D
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  14 | 24 | 34 | D is not in the expected results because B.B2 = 0 and there was no rule to lookup only by A.A1 = B.B1 AND A.A3 = B.B3

Comment: Is LATERAL an SQL standard or is it only PostgreSQL ?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand LATERAL in your statement, the joined statements ljl* are not referencing each other, so how does this differ from the same example but without using LATERAL

Comment: LATERAL is a recent adfition to SQL standards but not widely implemented as yet.

Comment: I'm sorry but I had pasted in an incorrect version of my suggestion. LATERAL joins are quite different, here I'm using LEFT JOIN LATERAL ON TRUE which permits a more efficient use of correlated subqueries (than a similar query in the select clause). `14 | 24 | 34 | D` is in my result because of the third subquery when a1 = b1 (it only needs to match on that one column) an a1 of 14 matches to a b1 of 14 and on tha row B4 = 'D'

Answer (score 0):

Quick Example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    CONCAT(B1,"-",B2,"-",B3) AS B_CONDITION1,
    CONCAT(B1,"-",B2) AS B_CONDITION2,
    B1 AS B_CONDITION3,
    b.*
    FROM b
) AS b_tmp
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
    CONCAT(A1,"-",A2,"-",A3) AS A_CONDITION1,
    CONCAT(A1,"-",A2) AS A_CONDITION2,
    A1 AS A_CONDITION3
    FROM a
) AS a_tmp ON 
(a_tmp.A_CONDITION1 = b_tmp.B_CONDITION1 OR a_tmp.A_CONDITION2 = b_tmp.B_CONDITION2 OR a_tmp.A_CONDITION3 = b_tmp.B_CONDITION3)
```

You must to see with big data it behaviour.. Sorry my english, **Good Work**!